# Open webapp added to home screen on iPhone

Tags: ios, safari, native, url-scheme, homescreen

I have a webapp which user can add to iPhone homescreen from Safari, and a native application for the same.

I want to open the full screen Webapp using URLScheme. I tried but safari opens instead of the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
  import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!          
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()      
            let url = NSURL (string: " **ENTER YOUR WEB APP URL HERE** ");
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
            webView.loadRequest(request);
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```